# Joining an array before using a displacement displacement map

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Stupid question, but here goes.  I am modelling a greyhound track.  I have used an array along a curve to create the track and am looking to use a displacement mask to create tracks in the procedural sand. I am now trying to get my head around how I can actually do this. I have applied the array and thought that the easiest solution would be to make the segments (of the quarter of the track that will be visible in the shot) into one piece, subdivide this with loop cuts and then use displacement. If that is the best way forward I am afraid I am failing at the first hurdle as I can't seem to join the segments.

Undoubtedly I am being dense but any advice would be welcomed.

Thanks

Adrian

Comment: Can you be more precise? What exactly is going on when you try to join the segments? Screenshots?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I am having problems posting a screenshot but in terms of details.  The track was made by modelling and texturing a section then using an array along a curve.  I have separated a segment out but when I Ctrl R I am only able to add loop cuts to one small segment. When I try any of the merge functions all of the segments disappear.

Comment: The fact though that Iam failing to add a screen shot may suggest that the answer is easier than it is in my head.  I could just be being an idiot.

Comment: @Adrian - You can add a screen shot by clicking the "edit" button under your original question and then clicking the add photo button [img]https://i.imgur.com/jdFtGMN.png[/img]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your situation is without a .blend file, or at least some screenshots. The best advice I can think of is: Apply the array modifier before doing anything else. If your going to use a displacement map after, then I guess you'll need to UV unwrap again.
Hope this helps